# Is it possible to have Drag and Drop in C# without moving the source to target?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, drag-and-drop, treelist

I am wondering if in the realm of UI design  the case exists where you drag one TreeList's item and drop onto another TreeList item only to invoke a new window (to perform some functioanlity) BUT not to actually move the source and drop it onto the target.

I have this as a requirement but I am not sure if it makes sense.

I thought Drag and Drop in a tree List is only to move one item to another branch of the tree, not to trigger a pop up. Am I mistaken?  The examples I have so far seen , all move the source to the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag and Drop is basically a set of events that get triggered.  The `Drop` event can be used by your code to do anything.  So triggering a popup on a drop is entirely possible.

Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx for more details.

```
void treeView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   var sourceNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode);

   // TODO: popup window
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it seems to me that once you set the AllowDrop to true. the physical move is inevitable. I looked at the documents you referred me to, although helpful,please let me know if you know of a complete example anywhere.  I have set my TreeList.AllowDrop = true  ; and in my Mouse_down event I call :                                                                   this.treeList1.DoDragDrop(this.treeList1.FocusedNode,DragDropEffects.None);  and I implement my DragDropEffects.None in all my event handlers for Drop and Drag but still the source UIItem MOVES?

Comment: Even with AllowDrop true, i believe you can set the DragDropEffects to NONE to avoid the physical move, but still use the DROP triggering event totrigger the popup: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdropeffects.aspx.